# Chessboard 5x5 with twentyfour"+1" and one "-1"

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, chessboard

A number $+1$ has been entered in 24 fields of the $5 \times 5$ array, and the number $-1$ in one. 
In one move, you can multiply by $ -1 $ all numbers in the subarray  $ k \times k $ where $ k> 1 $.
Which field at the beginning contained the number $ -1 $, since after a finite number of moves you can get to the state with twentyfive $ + 1 $ 


I have already proved that that $-1$ cannot be written in fields with $a$ since every subarray contains even number of fields with the letter $a$, therefore the product of the numbers in fields with letter $ a $ would be negative, which leads to a contradiction.
\begin{matrix}
b & b & a & b & b \\
b & b & a & b & b \\
a & a & 0 & a & a \\
b & b & a & b & b \\
b & b & a & b & b 
\end{matrix}
However I'm not able to to disprove the possibility of $-1$ in fields with letter $b$. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about the case that the middle square is $-1$ at the beginning ?

Comment: Then we can reach the state with twentyfive $+1$

Comment: If you can solve for middle square $(3,3)$ than you can solve for square $(2,2)$ also. Sequence of moves $(1-2;2-3), (2-3,1-2)$, $(1-3,3-5), (3-5,1-3)$, $(1-2,4-5), (4-5,1-2)$, $(3-5,3-5), (4-5,4-5)$ changes sign of exactly $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ squares. I use notation $(row_1-row_2,column_1-column_2)$ for moves, where $row_2-row_1=column_2-column_1=k$.

Comment: You proved that if you can solve for $(1,2)$, you can solve for $(2,1)$, unless i missed something

Comment: A tool would be nice where we can make moves and follow the change of the signs.

Comment: No I'm wrong, but it seems that your sequence leaves (3,3), (1,2), (2,1) from a full $1$ board.